# Change fullwidth characters to halfwidth

Tags: php, javascript

```
"合同会社Ｋｎｏｗｌｅｄｇｅ　Ｌｉｂｒａｒｙ" => "合同会社Knowledge Library"
```

I want to convert only alphanumeric characters in the string to single byte using java script or php

Comment: Both strings look the same to me. Is that a typo?

Comment: Looks same but the bytes are different, Use shift js encoding you can find the difference in bytes

Comment: @Jack Then your system does not render it properly. The full width forms should be as wide as the Chinese characters, not proportionally spaced as usual.

Comment: @deceze I saw the difference in rendering, but I assumed it was SO formatting problem ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PHP, use [`mb_convert_kana`](http://php.net/mb_convert_kana) to convert "zen-kaku" to "han-kaku".

Comment: "Convert "zen-kaku hira-gana" to "han-kaku kata-kana" " *The hyphens, they burn!*

Comment: I don-t kn-ow wh-at you-re talk-ing a-bout.

Comment: And use the 'r' option to convert full width letters to half width.

Comment: @deceze
'<?php
$str = "合同会社Ｋｎｏｗｌｅｄｇｅ　Ｌｉｂｒａｒｙ";
$str = mb_convert_kana($str, "KVr");
echo $str;
?>'

I used the code above but no use, Anything wrong

Comment: @Pradeep You're looking either for `'a'` or `'r'` conversion, not `'KV'`. Also try specifying the encoding: `mb_convert_kana($str, 'a', 'UTF-8')`.

Comment: @deceze  
Thanks a lot  
`<?php
$str = "合同会社Ｋｎｏｗｌｅｄｇｅ　Ｌｉｂｒａｒｙ";  
$str = mb_convert_kana($str, 'a', 'UTF-8');  
echo $str;  
?>`
Its working for me